# Parts Missing From Plot, That then Reappear and Overwrite The Entire Plot When Saved? (R, Heatmap.2)

Tags: r, matrix, plot, device, heatmap

I'm using heatmap.2 to create a plot, however, the initial plot that is saved to my source folder is missing a key and title.

When I then run the `dev.off()` command, the Key and the Title are then used to overwrite the original graph?

For instance, I will produce a plot like this:

[image]

Which is far from perfect. But then when I run the `dev.off()` to close the device (otherwise a host of other errors ensue):

[image]

What you are looking at above is a very distorted Key and my 'XYZ' title.

Why on earth is it creating two files, firstly the one with my matrix, and then overwriting this with a second file containing my flipping key and my title? I cannot follow the logic.

I've updated my OS, my version of R, RStudio, all my packages and unistalled RStudio. Nothing seems to help.

If you'd like to try and replicate my error here is the example matrix:

```
structure(c(1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 
2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 9, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L))
```

And this is the script I'm using to plot my example data. You'll need to provide a SourceDir and make sure you assign the matrix to the name "Matrix".

```
if (!require("gplots")) {
  install.packages("gplots", dependencies = TRUE)
  library(gplots)
}
if (!require("RColorBrewer")) {
  install.packages("RColorBrewer", dependencies = TRUE)
  library(RColorBrewer)
}

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("snow", "yellow", "darkorange", "red"))(n = 399)


transition
    col_breaks = c(seq(0,1,length=100),    #white 'snow'
                   seq(2,4,length=100), # for yellow
                   seq(5,7,length=100), # for orange 'darkorange'
                   seq(8,9,length=100))    # for red


png(paste(SourceDir, "Heatmap_Test.png"),      
    width = 5*1000,       
    height = 5*1000,
    res = 300,           
    pointsize =15)

heatmap.2(Matrix,
          main =  paste("XYZ"), 
          notecol="black",
          key = "true" ,
          colsep = c(3, 6, 9),
          rowsep = c(3, 6, 9),
          labCol = NULL,
          labRow = NULL,
          sepcolor="white",
          sepwidth=c(0.08,0.08),
          density.info="none",  
          trace="none",         
          margins=c(1,1),     
          col=my_palette,       
          breaks=col_breaks,    
          dendrogram="none",     
          RowSideColors = c(rep("blue", 3), rep("orange", 3)),
          ColSideColors = c(rep("blue", 3), rep("orange", 3)),
          srtCol = 0 ,        
          asp = 1 ,         
          adjCol = c(NA, 0) , 
          adjRow = c(0, NA) , 
          #keysize =  2 ,  
          Colv = FALSE ,      
          Rowv =  FALSE ,    
          key.xlab = paste("Correlation") , 
          cexRow = (1.8) , 
          cexCol = (1.8) , 
          notecex = (1.5) , 
          lmat = rbind(c(0,0,0,0), c(0,0,2,0),c(0,1,3,0),c(0,0,0,0)) , 
          #par(ColSideColors = c(2,2)),
          lhei = c(1, 1, 3, 1) , 
          lwid = c(1, 1, 3, 1)) 

dev.off()
```

I'd really appreciate any insight into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this resulted from the fact that I had more than just elements 1 to four, as the coloured rows I had added counted as additional elements that had to be arranged in the display matrix.

As such:

```
mat = rbind(c(0,0,0,0), c(0,0,2,0),c(0,1,3,0),c(0,0,0,0)) , 
lhei = c(1, 1, 3, 1) , 
lwid = c(1, 1, 3, 1))
```

No longer cut the butter. After much ado, I finally managed to get the following layout to work (on my actual data, not my example data).

```
lmat = rbind(c(0,4,5,0), c(0,0,2,0),c(0,1,3,0),c(0,0,6,0)) , 
lhei = c(0.4, 0.16, 3, 0.4) , # Alter dimensions of display array cell heighs
lwid = c(0.4, 0.16, 3, 0.4),
```

Notice the inclusion of elements 5 and 6.

So my final command looks like this (note that there will be many other changes but the real progress happened once I added in 5 and 6):

```
png(paste(SourceDir, "XYZ.png"),         
    width = 5*1500,        
    height = 5*1500,
    res = 300,            # 300 pixels per inch
    pointsize =30)        

heatmap.2(CombinedMtx,
          main =  paste("XYZ"), # heat map title
          notecol="black",
          key = "true" ,# change font color of cell labels to black
          colsep = c(6, 12, 18),
          labCol = c(" "," "," ", "XX"," "," "," "," "," ", "YY"," "," "," "," "," ", "ZZ"," "," "," "," "," ", "QQ"),
          rowsep = c(6, 12, 18),
          labRow = c(" "," "," ", "XX"," "," "," "," "," ", "YY"," "," "," "," "," ", "ZZ"," "," "," "," "," ", "QQ"),
          sepcolor="white",
          sepwidth=c(0.08,0.08),
          density.info="none",  
          trace="none",         
          margins=c(1,1),     
          col=my_palette,      
          breaks=col_breaks,   
          dendrogram="none",     
          RowSideColors = c(rep("#deebf7", 6), rep("#1c9099", 6), rep("#addd8e", 6), rep("#fee391", 6)),
          ColSideColors = c(rep("#deebf7", 6), rep("#1c9099", 6), rep("#addd8e", 6), rep("#fee391", 6)),
          srtCol = 0 ,        
          asp = 1 ,         
          adjCol = c(1.5, -61.5) , 
          adjRow = c(0, -1.38), 
          offsetRow = (-59.5),
          keysize =  2 ,  
          Colv = FALSE ,     
          Rowv =  FALSE ,    
          key.xlab = NA , 
          key.ylab = NULL ,
          key.title = NA ,
          cexRow = (1.6) , 
          cexCol = (1.6) , 
          notecex = (1.5) , 
          cex.main = (20),
          lmat = rbind(c(0,4,5,0), c(0,0,2,0),c(0,1,3,0),c(0,0,6,0)) , 
          #par(ColSideColors = c(2,2)),
          lhei = c(0.4, 0.16, 3, 0.4) , # Alter dimensions of display array cell heighs
          lwid = c(0.4, 0.16, 3, 0.4),
          symkey = any(0.5 < 0, na.rm=FALSE) || col_breaks,
          key.par=list(mar=c(3.5,0, 1.8,0) )  #tweak specific key paramters
)
dev.off()
```

Also, if you don't start each time by creating the PNG and enf each time by using `dev.off()` it won't work. I believe this might also have been contribution to my confusion, and potentially after drawing the heatmap, some elements were being drawn once the dev.off() command was run, causing the heatmap to be overwritten.

This (with my matrix) creates this image.

[image]

What I have done is a really gammy way of labelling my blocks but until I can work out how to get `ComplexHeatmap` working properly I'll be stuck using hacks like this with `Heatmap.2`.