# Dividing by Columns & Rows Doesn't Work with 'ComplexHeatmap' - Even Using Their Own Example?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, bioinformatics

I'm currently trying to assemble a heatmap using `ComplexHeatmap`. However, when I try to divide my heatmap by columns and rows it doesn't work.

When I go back to the [documentation](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-single-heatmap.html#split-by-categorical-variables) that accompanies `ComplexHeatmap` I have discovered that their own example will not work, returning an error message of `unused arguments`. I was wondering whether someone would be able to shed some light on what might be going on.

Here is the example matrix:

```
set.seed(123)
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 6; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))
```

Which gives you the following:

[image]

And here is the command demonstrating how to use row and column split:

```
install.packages('ComplexHeatmap')


Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", 
        row_split = rep(c("A", "B"), 9), column_split = rep(c("C", "D"), 12))
```

Here is the output the creators of ComplexHeatmap say I should expect, which as you can see is nicely divided into four tiles.

[image]

But all I get is the following error message:

```
Error in Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", row_split = rep(c("A", "B"), 9), column_split = rep(c("C",  : 
  unused arguments (row_split = rep(c("A", "B"), 9), column_split = rep(c("C", "D"), 12))
```

As even the example they provide doesn't work I'm struggling to make any headway.

I've already swapped packages once as for some reason [heatmap.2](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/versions/3.0.1.1/topics/heatmap.2) began behaving highly erratically, for which I have raised [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690285/parts-missing-from-plot-that-then-reappear-and-overwrite-the-entire-plot-when-s?fbclid=IwAR3F4KA1g5aSzgw30H4VTuBhRk05eC2-qeL5Bjn6NCuQgZrCSK7a80yS85E) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite having the latest version, running the following seemed to resolve the problem I had been having.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap", force = TRUE)
```

Even though running,

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap")
```

Produced the following,

```
Skipping install of 'ComplexHeatmap' from a github remote, the SHA1 (c79aaf9e) has not changed since last install.
```

Entirely my own fault for not forcing a reinstall from the start really.